# Separating similar object in an image - opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I am trying to detect the objects in an image which look similar to the reference image. Here is how i'm trying to accomplish it:

Here is the sample Image:

[image]

and here is the image with SURF keypoints:

[image]

The rectangle is drawn based on Clustering method like "Hierarchial Clustering".

The main problem is, in this case it doesnt detect the objects individually, it detects everything as one object.

Is there a way to seperate these keypoints, so as to detect each vehicle seperately?
Is this a good way to detect objects or if there is a better way please suggest.

Comment: Read [this: Rapid Detection of Many Object Instances](http://vgl-ait.org/mdailey/uploads/publication_file/filename/62/Tongphu-ObjectDetect.pdf)

Comment: The rectangle seems to be drawn only considering a bounding box that involves all the points found. I don't see the relevance of that caption, is there any ?

Comment: Since your objects are "stacked" you could try to detect the first like in this tutorial ( http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html ) and then remove the already matched keypoints and repeat until nothing is found any more.

Comment: Perhaps you have to write your own KeyPointsMatcher for this. One, that also consideres the relative position of the points, not just their descriptors.

Comment: Image processing questions are better suited to dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvgl-ait.org%2Fmdailey%2Fuploads%2Fpublication_file%2Ffilename%2F62%2FTongphu-ObjectDetect.pdf&ei=NqIOUdLHHobJiwKqq4FQ&usg=AFQjCNHU6U68clM8c-Uhi6zNIgr76FMZgA&sig2=7DmpGWbREj6ZoxpMAUJrbA&bvm=bv.41867550,d.cGE) is a link to a paper on rapid detection of multiple images in a single image. It's a bit... um... technical.

Answer (score 1):

SURF keypoints are useful in detecting similar images, or images taken of the same place from different perspectives. Although you can use [Haar classifiers](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html) for the purpose of object detection. It is also a part of OpenCV library.

[Here](http://www.ces.clemson.edu/~stb/ece877/.../objectdetect_tutorial.ppt) is another great tutorial regarding object detection using OpenCV.

Comment: 2nd link doesn't work. Are you sure that Haar classifier will help? Can you prove it?

Comment: @stack programmer: i've already mentioned that I am using SURF, my question is "how can we seperate the keypoints for each object in a frame wherein similar objects are present" as in the above imatge

Comment: For future travelers... [second link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ces.clemson.edu%2F~stb%2Fece877%2Fspring2007%2Fobjectdetect_tutorial.ppt&ei=wqEOUffcOczFiwKxvYCABw&usg=AFQjCNHz7lBcsP8mZEVUVc37yP9CJeyTyA&sig2=-BdLUgTHBtZfToq0uUodZg&bvm=bv.41867550,d.cGE).